# ¿Cómo mostrar cambios en un calendario, vuejs?

Tags: javascript, array, firebase, vue.js, map

Componente:

```
<template>
 <v-layout wrap>
    <v-sheet height="500">
      <v-calendar ref="calendar" v-model="start" :now="today" 
       color="primary">
        <template v-slot:day="{ date }">
          <template v-for="event in eventsMap[date]">
            <v-menu :key="event.index" v-model="event.open">
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                  <v-chip small v-ripple v-on="on">
                   {{event.type}}
                  </v-chip>
              </template>                    
            </v-menu>
          </template>
        </template>
      </v-calendar>
    </v-sheet>
```

Script:

```
<script>
import db from '@/firebase'
import format from 'date-fns/format'
 export default {
 data () {
  return{
    type: 'month',
    today: format(new Date(),"YYYY-MM-DD"),
    start: format(new Date(),"YYYY-MM-DD"),
    end: '2019-04-01',
    events: []
  }
},
computed: {
  eventsMap () {
    const map = {}
    if(this.events != []){
      this.events.forEach(e => (
        map[e.start_date] = map[e.start_date] || []
        ).push(e)
      )
    }
    return map
  }
 },
  created(){
    db.collection('events').onSnapshot(res => {
       res.forEach(doc => {
        this.events.push(doc.data())
       })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

En donde obtengo un array al inicio y mapeo con la función 'eventsMap' para así pintar en mi calendario las fechas obtenidas
Mi problema está que al agregar otra fecha o realizar cualquier modificación el pintado se duplica,
Lo que quiero hacer es pintar solamente los cambios en mi calendario..

Json(return de Variable computada 'eventsMap') :

```
{
 2019-03-28:[
     description: "..."
     employee: "User"
     start_date: "2019-03-28"
     type: "vacation"
 ],
 2019-04-28:[
     description: "..."
     employee: "User"
     start_date: "2019-04-28"
     type: "vacation"
 ]
}
```

Inicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de añadir otra tarea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este caso, si necesitariamos ver las pantallas antes y despues, para que quede bien claro que queres decir con que se duplica (no podes pintar sobre lo pintado)

Comment: Ya agregué el antes y el después de mi calendario, la fecha que añadí fue solamente la del día 23, las demás las duplica, vuelve a hacer el pintado..

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la variable computada no tendria que agregar todo de vuelta al array del calendario. O limpias el array y lo volves a generar, o comprobas si cada elemento no existe y si es asi lo agregas

Comment: Me podrías dar un ejemplo?

Comment: @R.Quiñonez tu error es que vuelves a hacer un push de tu consulta de base de datos,`this.events.push(doc.data())`

Comment: Ya agregué el json que pinta el calendario, ¿Cómo hago para mostrar el nuevo evento guardado, sin volver a hacer el push?

Comment: cambia tu if a `if(!this.events || this.events.lenght == 0)` estas comparando objetos distintos(los arrays tambien son objetos, pero especiales) al hacer [] esta haciendo un new Array()

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya solucioné el problema.